# Here's a mathematical conjecture that I want to show to the world, but how? It's basic, but useful. It's a triangular number array.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My name is Christopher Njoku and here it
\begin{align}
                                                        1\\
                                                        2\, 2\\
                                                       3\,4\, 3\\
                                                     4\, 6\, 6\, 4\\
                                                   5\, 8\, 9\, 8\, 5\\
                                               6 \,10\, 12\, 12\, 10\, 6\\
                                             7 12 15 16 15 12 7\\
                                          8 14 18 20 20 18 14 8\\
                                        9 16 21 24 25 24 21 16 9\\
                                   10 18 24 28 30 30 28 24 18 10\\
                                 11 20 27 32 35 36 35 32 27 20 11\\
                              12 22 30 36 40 42 42 40 36 30 22 12\\
                           13 24 33 40 45 48 49 48 45 40 33 24 13\\
                         14 26 36 44 50 54 56 56 54 50 44 36 26 14\\
\end{align}
Features:

1. It is divided into odd and even sets
2. Every odd set gas a square as it medium
3. Each set(x) has x numbers
4. Every number in an even set is even
5. The sum of every number in a set is a tetrahedral number
6. The sum of every number in two consecutive sets is a square pyramidal number
7. The difference between  the sum of every number in two consecutive sets is a triangular number, which is the same number of elements in set(x) and every set before it
8. It is symmetrical
9. A number' s multiple moves down diagonally, and crosses path at its square So far the formula that I have for the display is for the relationship for consecutive odd numbers of the number theory, if you want to check out others go myconjectureblog for others like a new solution to time travel paradoxes. I discovered this since I was 14. I didn't display the formula for personal reasons.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @vonbrand I've editted a bit, it's a triangle of numbers with some properties.

Comment: @Christopher, Take a look at my edit and continue it, I got tired.

Comment: An immediate google search led me to this: https://oeis.org/A003991/list

Comment: What is so special about this? Can you show a use for this.

Comment: It seems nice (after the edit, that is), but calling it a *mathematical conjecture* is going too far me thinks.

Comment: @ThePortakal Thanks for the link.  https://oeis.org/A003991/table shows it is just the multiplication table.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not entirely sure what you're conjecturing, but your sequence seems to be well known: https://oeis.org/A003991

Comment: I thought I deleted my question, do anybody know how to, it was a mistake from my friend. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Also, please don't be disheartened, it's an interesting sequence, even if it has been discovered before. Mathematicians often end up realizing that other people have discovered something first. You don't need to be ashamed of the fact that this has happened to you too/try to hide all evidence of this.

Comment: @ChristopherNjoku You can only delete a question when there doesn't exist an answer with at least one upvote.